# how to override onresume for google maps

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm showing map via startActivity as intent, as like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?     
saddr=20.565442,80.35622213&daddr=21.24363633,80.7655222"));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");    
startActivity(intent);
```

And this is working fine. but how to override onresume and onpause for that map?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you should implement your own MapActivity.